# Automate text replace in Visual Studio

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, automation, replace

I have a web project that I am ripping out all the inline styling and adding it to a CSS file, and I can't help but think there is an easier way to do this.

My current process is:

1. Search Solution for `style="`, if none selected, goto: `9`
2. Cut all the text between the quote marks
3. Create new class in CSS file
4. Paste code in class
5. Copy class name
6. Return to html line and paste class name in between quote marks
7. Rename `style` to `class`
8. goto: `1`
9. Rejoice!

I would really like to rejoice, but there seems to be a never ending supply of inline styling.

Is there a way to automate this process in Visual Studio 2010?  If it requires writing a plugin, that is totally fine!  I have this same task to do on many a project.

Also, I'd like to be able to do this for arbitrary tags. For example, I'm also taking all of the `data-*` tags and doing roughly the same thing, but adding a line of jQuery to add it back in.  Something like:

```
$('SELECTOR').attr('data-bind','visible: IsValid');
```

The work is too repetitious for me not to believe there is an automated (or at least faster/better/less time consuming) way of doing this.

The project is an MVC project if that changes anything.

Comment: I don't know of a way, I'd use [LinqPad](http://linqpad.net) and script it in C#. Start by Parsing the project file for a file list, then work on each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for tool to replace inline style to css class, there are tools available:

http://www.voodoobytes.info/humbles-tools/

http://www.tinytool.net/96002/inline_css_extractor

Answer (score 1):

You will need a macro. There are hints for realization in one file:

1/ Edit point

```
Dim EditPt As EditPoint
EditPt = CType(DTE.ActiveDocument.Object, EnvDTE.TextDocument).StartPoint.CreateEditPoint
```

2/ Searching and replacing

```
While EditPt.FindPattern("style="".*""")

End While
```

You can read text `EditPt.GetText(6)` (returns 'style=') delete text `EditPt.Delete(6)` (removes 'style=') `EditPt.Insert("_")` (inserts _ before 'style=').

Answer (score 0):

I don't use [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/index.xml) myself, but they seem to have what you are looking for, if [this link](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/index.xml#maintc|whatsinside) is anything to be believed.

> - Move Style Attributes to External CSS

You may need to write your own plugin to do the other, but CodeRush do support this.

I was unable to find similar functionality in [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), although it does support plugins as well..